# Inability to instantiate a standard facet

Tags: c++

Naturally it isn't possible to instantiate a facet, since a facet doesn't encapsulate any specific functionality, instead leaving that to specific classes derived from facet, such as collate, etc.

Ie, the facet class is designed to be a base class.

For this reason, to prevent a facet being instantiated directly, its constructor is protected and destructor is virtual (to ensure proper destruction of derived-class objects):

```
class locale::facet
{
protected:
   explicit facet(size_t refs = 0);

   virtual ~facet();

   facet(const facet&) = delete;
   void operator=(const facet&) = delete;
};
```

However, now consider the standard facet collate, which is derived from facet:

```
template<typename C>
class collate : public locale::facet
{
public:
   /// ...

protected:
   ~collate();      /// note: protected destructor

   virtual int do_compare(
                  const C* b, const C* e,
                  const C* b2, const C* e2) const;

   virtual string_type do_transform(
                          const C* b,
                          const C* e) const;

   virtual long do_hash(const C* b,
                        const C* e) const;
};
```

Notice that here too, the destructor is protected. Therefore you won't be able to instantiate a collate. If you try to do so, you will get an error:

```
collate<char> colc;
```

The error is:

```
error: 'std::collate<_CharT>::~collate() [with _CharT = char]' is protected|
```

Yet, the collate template class's protected members (do_compare(), do_transform() and do_hash()) all contain encapsulated functionality and there was no need for the standard facet collate to have been declared with a protected dtor.

For this reason, to create a collate, we need to first derive a class from collate, which can then be instantiated!

```
template<typename C>
class My_collate : public collate<C>
{
public:
    explicit My_collate(size_t r = 0) :
        collate<C> {r}
    {
    }
};

My_collate<char> mcolc;
```

This successfuly creates a My_collate (which is a collate by derivation).

Just to prove that My_collate encapsulates inherited functionality, I have successfully tested it:

```
void print(const string& s1, const string& s2,
           const int& rslt)
{
    string srslt {};

    switch(rslt)
    {
    case 0:
        srslt = "equal";
        break;

    case 1:
        srslt = "s1 > s2";
        break;


    case -1:
        srslt = "s1 < s2";
        break;
    }

    cout << "comparison of " << s1 << " and " << s2
         << " using the mcolc facet : "
         << srslt << endl;
}


void test(const string& s1, const string& s2)
{
    /// since compare() operates on char[]s
    const char* s1b = s1.data();        /// start of data
    const char* s1e = s1b + s1.size();  /// end of data
    const char* s2b = s2.data();        /// start of data
    const char* s2e = s2b + s2.size();  /// end of data

    int rslt = mcolc.compare(s1b, s1e, s2b, s2e);

    /// display results
    print(s1, s2, rslt);
}


int main()
{
    test("Hello", "Hello");
    test("Hello", "hello");
    test("hello", "Hello");
}
```

https://ideone.com/D6zrbr

Here's the output:

```
comparison of Hello and Hello using the mcolc facet : equal
comparison of Hello and hello using the mcolc facet : s1 < s2
comparison of hello and Hello using the mcolc facet : s1 > s2
```

So, my question is: Why do standard facets such as collate have a protected destructor, so as to prevent direct instantiation, when they already encapsulate the full required functionality?

Thanks.

Comment: According to [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/locale/facet), `facet` contains reference counts that `std::locale` use to manage their lifetime. It would probably be a mess if you could pass a `facet` with automatic storage duration to a `std::locale`, e.g. `std::collate<char> c; std::locale(loc, c);`.

Comment: No. In fact `collate<char> c` (if such an op were possible) would create a facet which must be managed by a locale, since the default ctor arg is 0,

Comment: Yes but as soon as you pass it to `std::locale(loc, &c)` (I forgot the `&` in my previous comment), the `locale` will increment the reference counter and start sharing the ownership of the `collate`, which will cause you problem when the locale tries to delete the `collate` at the end of its lifetime. You should never add a facet with automatic storage duration to locale, which is probably why this destructor is protected. My point was that this prevents you from doing something wrong without knowing it, which is basically the answer you got on cplusplus.com.

Comment: By 'automatic storage duration', I think you mean a facet created with the ctor arg refs = 0 (default value); ie, a facet whose lifetime is managed by a locale. As far as I am aware, for a facet to be added to a locale, the facet's lifetime _must_ be managed by the locale, rather than manually. Why do you say this shouldn't be done?

Comment: By *automatic storage duration*, I was referring to the [storage duration](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration) of the `collate`, i.e. it is a `std::collate` thas was not allocated using `new` (basically a local variable on the stack). If you have such a `std::collate` object, you cannot use it with a `std::locale` because the locale will try to `delete` it, which will cause UB since the `std::collate` was not allocated with `new`. I do understand the confusion since the `facet` are in a sense "automatically" managed, but I was not referring to the counter ;)

Comment: I see what you mean. Firstly, I get the point about the locale giving an error if it were to manage a facet created on the stack, and I agree that it would. However, it surprises me that I have written a few programs in which a locale does just that, and it gave no error! Secondly, however, what does this have to do with the original query - why should standard facets have a protected destructor, for this reason? Thirdly, this opens up another issue on the side - having to use a unique_ptr to store a dynamically-created facet, to prevent leaks.

Comment: Having a protected destructor prevent you from easily creating variable on the "stack", you'd have to inherit it as you did. You don't want to use a unique_ptr or only with a custom deleter because in all cases you want to let the locale manage the facet.

Answer (score 0):

I had posted this query on [another forum](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/227484/).

Based on the reply, it appears that this action was deliberate on the part of the C++ standard setters, to prevent novices from instantiating standard-library facets, such as collate.

After all, as Stroustrup states ["The C++ Programming Language", 4th Ed, pg 1125],

```
It is essential for one to have a detailed knowledge of individual facets, 
to be able to successfully mix and match facets or add new versions of 
the standard facets.
```